# How to add model panel to layout created in designer in maya PySide

Tags: python, pyside, maya

I am creating a script in i want to place a model panel in a grig layout created in QtDesigner.

[image]

model panel has to be placed in the red area. I tried

```
cmds.setParent(self.LAY_grid_modelEditor)
cmds.modelPanel('testEditor', cam='persp')
cmds.setParent('..')
```

but getting the error

> RuntimeError: setParent: Object '' not found.

I am using PySide in Maya 2015.

Any Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is actually I took it from http://nathanhorne.com/embedding-a-maya-widget-into-a-pyqt-ui/, which will show how you can embed a maya gui inside pyqt. This same method you can use for pyside too. This example code I modified and now it will load a modelPane

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sip

def getMayaWindow():
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)

def toQtObject(mayaName):
    '''
    Given the name of a Maya UI element of any type,
    return the corresponding QWidget or QAction.
    If the object does not exist, returns None
    '''
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findControl(mayaName)
    if ptr is None:
        ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findLayout(mayaName)
    if ptr is None:
        ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findMenuItem(mayaName)
    if ptr is not None:
        return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)

class MayaSubWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=getMayaWindow()):
        super(MayaSubWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.modelPne = cmds.modelPanel('testEditor', cam='persp')
        qtObj = toQtObject(self.modelPne)
        self.setCentralWidget(qtObj)

myWindow = MayaSubWindow()
myWindow.show()
```